# Is it OK to use a hair dryer on underground lawn sprinkler pipe?

Tags: repair, sprinkler-system, plastic, leaks

Repairing black sprinkler pipe when it is chilly outside, i have used a hair dryer to make the plastic pipe more supple.  Makes it much easier to fit the pipe over the repair couplers.  Does the heat damage the pipe?  Other than being electrocuted, [is it a bad idea](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66490/is-it-normal-for-a-1-lawn-sprinkler-repair-to-leak-only-under-pressure)?   Why?

Comment: What kind of pipe are you repairing, black poly pipe?

Comment: Black pipe.  Edited question specify black.

Comment: Have asked many others and none of them actually pressure tested their repairs.